Unable to integrate Google Play Games Services Sign In v2 on Android Studio - Kotlin
I'm having some troubles with client integration with Play Games Services Sign In v2. I've done everything shown here, but the Sign In v2 still not works. Nothing is shown on the application startup as it should be according to the documentation. I've tried my application with both emulator and physical device.
I leave there my sources. Any suggestions will be appreciated :)
AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.LevelUpXPBooster"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/game_services_project_id"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.LevelUpXPBooster">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

strings.xml
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Level Up - XP Booster</string>
<string translatable="false"  name="game_services_project_id">VALUE_PROJECT_ID</string>
</resources>

The VALUE_PROJECT_ID in string.xml is replaced with the 12-digits code found in the Google Play Console under the section Play Games services > Setup and management > Configuration (the code darkened in the image below).

MainActivity.kt
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.rounded.Build
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.danielemenchetti.levelup_xpbooster.ui.theme.LevelUpXPBoosterTheme
import com.google.android.gms.games.AuthenticationResult
import com.google.android.gms.games.PlayGames
import com.google.android.gms.games.PlayGamesSdk
import com.google.android.gms.games.Player
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            LevelUpXPBoosterTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    LevelUpXpBooster()
                }
            }
        }
        
        PlayGamesSdk.initialize(this)

        val gamesSignInClient = PlayGames.getGamesSignInClient(this@MainActivity)

        gamesSignInClient.isAuthenticated()
            .addOnCompleteListener { isAuthenticatedTask: Task<AuthenticationResult> ->
                val isAuthenticated =
                    (isAuthenticatedTask.isSuccessful &&
                            isAuthenticatedTask.result.isAuthenticated)

                if (isAuthenticated) {
                    // Continue with Play Games Services
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Succesful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()

                    PlayGames.getPlayersClient(this@MainActivity).currentPlayer.addOnCompleteListener {
                        mTask: Task<Player?>? ->
                        if (mTask != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "${mTask.result?.playerId}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show()
                        }

                    }
                } else {
                    // Disable your integration with Play Games Services or show a
                    // login button to ask  players to sign-in. Clicking it should
                    // call GamesSignInClient.signIn().

                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()


                    //gamesSignInClient.signIn()
                }
            }
      } 
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun LevelUpXpBooster(){

    var buttonText by remember {mutableStateOf("Boost!")}

    val customTextStyle = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = FontFamily.Monospace,
        fontSize = 32.sp,
        color = Color.Red
    )


    Column (
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ){

        Text(
            "Level Up",
            style = customTextStyle
        )
        Text(
           "XP Booster",
            style = customTextStyle
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

        Button(onClick = {buttonClick()}) {
            Text(buttonText)
            Icon(Icons.Rounded.Build, contentDescription = "Arrow Down")
        }

    }
}

fun buttonClick(){

}

settings.gradle.kts
 pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "Level Up - XP Booster"
include(":app")

gradle-wrapper.properties
#Sat Jun 01 11:58:20 CEST 2024
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

build.gradle.hts (Module :app)
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.danielemenchetti.levelup_xpbooster"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.danielemenchetti.levelup_xpbooster"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-games-v2:20.1.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.3")
    implementation("androidx.credentials:credentials:1.2.2")
    implementation("androidx.credentials:credentials-play-services-auth:1.2.2")
    implementation("com.google.android.libraries.identity.googleid:googleid:1.1.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:21.2.0")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.8.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.9.0")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.06.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.06.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}

build.gradle.kts (Project: Level_Up_-_XP_Booster)
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
}

Once I run the application I got a Toast message with the string "Failed!" and the Logcat output produced is shown below:

